# Как конвертировать float/double в строку именно в том виде, в котором значение устновленно в переменной (без обрезки занков)?

Tags: c++, строки, форматирование

К своему удивлению не нашёл функции записи float/double в строку в исходном виде переменной:

```
float val = 0.012345678900000;
std::string strval;
snprintf(&strval[0], strval.capacity(), "%g", val);
printf("%s\n", strval.data());
```

Выводит "0.01234567", а надо "0.012345678900000". `stringstream` пробовал - результат тот же. `std::to_string` вообще 6 знаков пишет после точки.
Точность заранее не известна, нужно выгружать в строку то, что есть, можно без нулей в конце.

Как это сделать?

Comment: А вы не задумывались, какова точность представления числа типом `float`?

Comment: @Harry с `double` картина не меняется

Comment: Ну, вы вообще бредом занимаетесь - в пустой `string` что-то писать...

Comment: Ну, конкретное количество нулей справа - это вы никак не получите. У гугла есть [библиотека](https://github.com/google/double-conversion), которая печататет числа с плавающей точкой за минимальное количество знаков, возможно это вам подойдет. (По идее, `std::to_chars` тоже должна так уметь, но пока ее завезли только в MSVC.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float  valf = 0.012345678900100;
double vald = 0.012345678900100;
printf("%.20f\n", valf);
printf("%.20lf\n", vald);
```

Вывод:

```
0.01234567910432815552
0.01234567890010000030
```

В любом случае в силу того, что числа с плавающей точкой представлены в итоге виде суммы степеней двойки, ожидать, что введенный строковый литерал или результат вычисления будет равен чему-то конкретному, не приходится.

Пробуйте

```
char buf[30];
sprintf(buf,"%.20lf",val);
string s = buf;
```

Или

```
ostringstream os;
os << setprecision(20) << vald;
string s = os.str();
cout << s << endl;
```

Только не пишите в никуда, как в вашем примере...

**Update**

К "артефактам", упомянутым в комментарии. Это не артефакты. Представим, что у нас есть возможность записи только 4 бит. Как вы представите, например, 1/5 в виде суммы дробей вида 1/2<sup>n</sup>?

1/8 + 1/16 + 1/128... Стоп! Уже не можем представить 1/128 - точности не хватает. Так что число 0.20 будет иметь вид 0.1875.

Это - ограничение самого представления. Ну невозможно в общем случае представить дробное число с помощью конечной суммы дробей вида 1/2<sup>n</sup>...

Comment: Спасибо. Оно то то понятно, что в никуда писать опасно, смущают вот эти "артефакты" в конце в виде "...30", которых нет в оригинале. А как-то можно приводить к E-нотации при переполнении значения?

Comment: См. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение, никогда не задумывался над этими деталями. Кстати, насчёт string - он не пустой, capacity у него 15 при конструировании (но это конечно просто для примера, так делать нельля )) )

Comment: Он пустой в том смысле, что `s.size()==0`